# Unable to use backticks to use tr linux command in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, command, ascii

`tr -d \\000-\\177 < #{file_path} | wc -c`

The above command is used to remove ascii characters and check word count.
While running the above command in ruby on rails using backticks, \000-\177 which needs to be considered as numbers range in octal format is being considered as string and is giving wrong results.

The above command works fine while we run on a file in linux terminal.

Some suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried quadruple backslashes to escape your double backslashes? I tested and it works for me (note I narrowed the ASCII match so that I'd get something other than 0):

```
`tr -d \\\\000-\\\\170 < Rakefile | wc -c`
=> "3\n"
```

Only 3 characters returned, a bunch of y's from my Rakefile

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.